# Web-based outlook app opens *.eml file correctly but desktop-based one hangs

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have an *.eml file that I've received from one of my coworkers. He said that it can't be opened with a desktop outlook app but with a web-based app it opens without any problems.

I checked it and indeed - in the web app it opens like any other message but when I tried to open it in my Outlook for Microsoft 365 app (version 2111 16.0.14701.20254, 64-bit) it hangs and only shows the title and the sender/recipients part.

The file itself is over 2MB in size but I don't think it would be a problem to render it, especially when the browser app is clearly able to do it instantly. It contains a quite long conversation with lots of forwarded messages and some small images.

Unfortunately, I can't show you the message or upload the file for you to check yourself because it's confidential but maybe you had similar issues and you know what's the reason for this weird outlook behavior.

If you want some more info, please ask me in the comment. Thanks

Comment: I've had similar issues with a task. The end conclusion I reached, is that if the body is too long or contains some strange text, outlook eventually can't work with it, but webmail does not have this issue. I expect that if you can somehow make the text shorter, outlook will start to understand it again.

Comment: I shrunk the message (the base64 encoded HTML part) and now it opens :) Thanks for your help. I really thought that the desktop app would perform better than the web-based one but clearly, I was badly wrong...

Comment: @gribvirus74 You might consider turning your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: Hi @gribvirus74, i have summarize your solution and post below, would you mind marking that as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@LPChip](https://superuser.com/users/311586/lpchip) said, if the message body is too long (I don't know the specific limit though), Outlook will not open it.

The "solution" is to open the message file in the text editor, find the body part of the message (usually it begins with `Content-Type: text/html` or you can just find the largest chunk of encoded data in the file) and delete some of it. If it doesn't work, delete some more, and eventually, it will open.

If you want to decode the message body but you don't have access to a web-based outlook app for some reason just use some online base64-text converter (eg. [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/)) or use some online *.eml file viewer.